# Keep Getting "Command PhasescriptExecution Failed with a nonzero exitcode

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, mapbox

I am a new ios developer and as soon as I add Mapbox after getting the Pod installed i get the error above. I just open the new updated project and the error appears out of nowhere, is there an issue with how I set it up? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually occurs in context of missing privileges on the project folder or in context of some weird cached dependency configuration.

**Try this for the privileges issue:**

```
chmod -R 755 {your_working_folder}
```

**Dependency issue:**

You can try following these steps:

1. Delete your Podfile.lock: You can use the command '-rm -rf Podfile.lock'
2. Delete your Pods folder: You can use the command '-rm -rf Pods'
3. Delete your .xcworkspace
4. Pod install
5. Clear your project: XCode> Product> Clean Build Folder

It would be very helpful, if you could provide the steps that you took that lead to the situation you are in now!

Comment: Hello, really appreciate the comment. I installed the pod from Mapbox and deleted everything. I tried seeing adding another pod would fix it to see if it was on Mapbox's side. Turned out that now my firebase pod is not working and I am getting the same error. I tried doing the chmod -R 755 {Folder} and in the terminal nothing happens. @Moritz